# Optional elements vs attributes

Tags: xml

I'm specifically looking for a decision whether to use an element or an attribute on this case:

Making it an attribute will entail other attributes that are only directly related to that specific attribute.

Making it an element will cause some element to contain that element but some won't.

It's like I have an entity that can either contain or not this another entity.  Which would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Use elements!

Attributes are much more limited - they can't have any internal structure, or multiple values - without inventing your own format, which is negating the point of XML. IMO, attributes are a hangover from HTML, and break the clean, extensible nature of XML.

The guideline I have used is, if it's actual data, use elements. If it's metadata *about* the data (e.g. a checksum, or an index) then it can go in attributes.

But: Attributes are shorter to type and transfer, which some people like.

http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight.  My concern is that that element won't be present in all of the elements making it inconsistent.  Is it a big deal when designing xml structure?

Comment: No, there's no problem in having elements that are optional. That's what XML is all about.

Comment: Would be nice if you could mark my answer as accepted, or at least vote it up, user1039024....